# Php post is blank. / Notice: Undefined index:

Tags: php

My form button not sending var via post.

I've followed the code example in the following links.

[PHP Pass variable to next page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/871858/php-pass-variable-to-next-page)

[HTML form is not sending $_POST values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14820421/html-form-is-not-sending-post-values)

[Send value of submit button when form gets posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22579616/send-value-of-submit-button-when-form-gets-posted)

but keep getting..

**Notice: Undefined index: test in /public_html/test/seats.php on line 3**

or blank page when using isset.

PAGE 1

```
foreach($res as $row) {


  $title = $row['Title'];

  $perfDate = $row['PerfDate'];
  $perfTime = $row['PerfTime'];

   echo "<tr>";
   echo "<td>".$title."</td>";
   echo "<td>".$perfDate."</td>";
   echo "<td>".$perfTime."</td>";
   echo "<td><form action='seats.php' method='post'>
   <input type= 'hidden' name='test' value=<?php echo $title;?> /> 
   <input type='submit' value='Submit'></form></td>";

   echo "</tr>";


}
```

[image]

Ultimately I will be passing row info, to build an SQL query on the next PHP page, however at the moment I am unable to send the even just the $title.

Using the below code gives me nothing so the issue must be with my POST in page 1?

PAGE 2

```
<?php

$value = "";
$value = isset($_POST['test']) ? $_POST['test'] : '';
echo $value;
?>
```

Comment: What do you get in `var_dump($_POST);` ?

Comment: This line looks suspicious: `<input type= 'hidden' name='test' value=<?php echo $title;?> />`  Where are the quotes around `$title`?

Comment: var_dump($_POST); gives array(1) { ["test"]=> string(5) " , with quotes around $title the result is the same.. array(1) { ["test"]=> string(5) "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line

```php
echo "<input type= 'hidden' name='test' value=<?php echo $title;?> />"
```

because the php tag is already opened the above line will output the php tag as a string.

to fix this you can simply do this `value=\"$title;\"`